# How to get @odata.etag value from JSON in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, odata, etag

Could someone explain me, why @odata.etag key behave different than other keys ? Why I can't get value (and how to get) from it like from other keys ?

```
using ... System.Generics.Collections, System.JSON

procedure TFMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JSonValue, SingleValue: TJSonValue;
  ValueArray: TJsonArray;
begin
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"@odata.context": "https://blablabla", "value": [{"@odata.etag": "W/\"blablan\"", "No": "X0001" }]}');

  ValueArray := (JSONValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('value') as TJSONArray;
  SingleValue :=  ValueArray.Items[0];

  memo1.Lines.Add(JSONValue.GetValue<string>('value[0].No'));                     //works , no double quotes
  memo1.Lines.Add(JSONValue.GetValue<string>('value[0].@odata.etag'));            //not works

  memo1.Lines.Add((SingleValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('No').ToString);          //works, double quotes
  memo1.Lines.Add((SingleValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('@odata.etag').ToString); //works, double quotes

  memo1.lines.Add(SingleValue.GetValue<string>('No'));                            //works , no double quotes
  memo1.lines.Add(SingleValue.GetValue<string>('@odata.etag'));                   //not works

end;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple - because the key contains the dot character (`.`) which is used as key separator in JSON path and therefore it requires special treatment.

To access such key in JSON path use quoted indexer:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(JSONValue.GetValue<string>('value[0]["@odata.etag"]'));
```

Single quoted indexer will work as well. You can also find that in [`TJSONPathParser`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONPathParser) documentation.

On the other hand [`TJSONObject.GetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.GetValue) (non-generic method of `TJSONObject`) works because it takes single key, not the whole path as an argument. You observed double quotes when you used `ToString` which is expected and [very well documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.ToString):

> ...
> This format is more readable than the one returned by .ToJSON.
> The string is double-quoted.

To get the raw string value use [`Value`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONString.Value) property:

```
memo1.Lines.Add((SingleValue as TJSONObject).GetValue('@odata.etag').Value);
```

Comment: Thank You very much, saved my week. I tried double quote it, just didn't think about square brackets.